# Tanach without Christian chapter divisions

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, mesorah-tradition

Is there a Tanach available that is not divided into Prakim, rather into Pesuchos or Sedorim etc. ?

The nonJewish origin of the chapters is shown at [Who Divided the Torah Into Weekly Readings, Chapters, and Verses?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/628399/jewish/Who-divided-the-Torah-into-weekly-readings-chapters-and-verses.htm)

> The division of the Scriptures into chapters (perakim) was done by
> non-Jews in the thirteenth century. They did so to facilitate their
> bible study, to make it easier to recall the exact source for any
> given verse.

[Bible – origin of chapters and verses](http://strangeside.com/bible-origin-of-chapters-and-verses/)

> **A Church Invention**
>
> Credit for dividing the Tanach into convenient chapter and verse
> generally goes to Cardinal Stephen Langton of France and England, who
> served as the Archbishop of Canterbury. He is thought to have created
> the chapters and verses in about 1205, which are used until this day.
> This was not too difficult a job since 617 out of his 779 chapters
> coincide with the parshiyos that existed since Sinai, while of the 162
> chapters that he invented, many are illogical, while some border on
> the heretical.

Comment: Would you accept one that does both?

Comment: It seems that these chapters have been accepted into common Jewish usage, and so far as I'm aware, as they serve a practical purpose, they are not chukka hagoyim.

Comment: @Charles I agree with that edit, but I would personally link to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1127/5323 to explain it. Just saying.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt the issue isn't chukas akum, it is a sensitivty that i don't want christians sitting on the page of my tanach, especially when Chazal broke it up already.

Comment: @DoubleAA i would be interested in the rationale for either one.

Answer (score 4):

The [Koren Tanach](http://korenpub.com/koren/intusd/tanakh/tanakh-bible/tanakh-1068.html) (a.ka.a the Jerusalem bible with its English translation) has both divisions; the original one on the outside  margin of the page, and the popular one on the inside.

Comment: As a heads-up: the link doesn't seem to work anymore -- I simply get a blank page with a bunch of scroll-down menus (that link to other portions of the website).

Comment: He asked for one without christian chapter divisions though. Of course loads of tanachs have the jewish divisions in them otherwise people would struggle to follow the leining in shul.. I'd guess pretty much any chumash used in a shul would have it. Hertz, Artscroll, Soncino

Answer (score 2):

With the issue mainly being in the *Chumash* (The Five Books of Moses), the *Lev Tahor* community's publishing house, *Hotzaas Daas*, has recently published a Hebrew-only *Chumash* using a revised numbering system without any problematic divisions.

Comment: what do you mean that the issue is mainly in Chumash?

Comment: @judahsimon Because only there is there a potential change in meaning, and the danger of ending aliyos wrongly.

Comment: if you assume that there was a purpose to chazal breaking down tanach into pesuchos ans stumos, then it would apply accros the board not just to chumash.

Comment: @judahsimon AFAIK Chazal did not break down anything. The Neviim etc. wrote it that way. But that aside, yes, it would. Only the problem is most severe regarding the Chumash. I think their plan was to print the entire Tanach, but they had to start somewhere, and as I mentioned, it was only recently published.

Comment: it doesn't make a difference who broke it down, whoever it was it was either the Neviim or Chazal later on (see bava basra 14b as to who wrote each sefer), the point is someone broke it down and it is an issue across the board. i still don't understand why chumash is any different than Nach.

Comment: @NBZ "danger of ending aliyos wrongly" How can you end an aliyah wrongly? You mean within 3 verses of a Parsha break?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes.​​

Comment: Noteworthy, in Nakh many old printings added parsha breaks at Christian breaks. So in a sense, it's more important to avoid it in Nakh when people aren't naturally as careful as with Chumash.